# C# Selenium: How to send each character in sendkeys();

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have always found that sending keys to a web page text box has been fast. I need to do something where instead of the keys being instantly typed, I want each character to have a delay / sleep. 
Example:

1. User enters “Apple” in the program. We take that as the string “string answer = Console.ReadLine();”.
2. We then send the keys to the web page text box by delaying each character e.g A *sleep* p *sleep* p *sleep* l *sleep* e.

That is what I currently need help with.

Comment: Why is it "too fast"?

Comment: It’s too fast for what I need it for. So I need to slow them down somehow

Comment: you can use Thread.Sleep(number); after each sendkey

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the string that you want to send pausing however much time you'd like (1 second in this example) like this:

```
foreach (char letter in answer)
{
   element.SendKeys(letter.ToString());

   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thread.Sleep` after each send character.and you can change number 10 and use each number .

```
string answer ="Apple";
char[] charArray = answer.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    element.SendKeys(charArray[i].ToString());
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));//10 is test
}
```